# Conditional Logic - Looping Parameter page on API, Power BI

Tags: api, powerbi, m

So the problem is: I wanna increment the parameter page (++1), until the last page. In the future get the data on the page and go to the next page.

EX:

https://api.github.com/repos/"
                & login & "/" & repository
                & "/issues?state=all&sort=created&page="
                & Text.From(**page**) // page is my variable

Thinking as JAVA man we just adding a variable and use for/while depending the situation.

Now, how to do that using **M language**?

I did the homework and this sites have some information:

toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/b/weblog/archive/2014/03/10/conditional-logic-in-power-query

https://seddryck.wordpress.com/2017/01/07/do-while-loop-with-power-bi-m-language/

But it's not working. :(

Anyone can help me?

I'm new in this M world.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat calling a function. Please note @Factorial. The @ is needed to repeat the function. I assume you can change the code below to fit you needs.

```
(Connector as text, Take as number) as list =>
let
    _token = Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary("" & Token & ""), BinaryEncoding.Base64),
    fGetData = (Skip as number) => Json.Document(Web.Contents("" & URL & Connector &"?skip=" & Number.ToText(Skip) & "&take=" & Number.ToText(Take) & "", [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer " & _token & ""]])),
    Factorial = (res, skip) =>
    if List.Count(res) < Take then res else Combine(res, skip + Take),
    Combine = (x, skip) => List.Combine({ x, @Factorial(fGetData(skip)[rows], skip) }),
    Result = Factorial(fGetData(0)[rows], 0)
in
Result
```